# Cannot access SMTP server

Tags: email

I'm running on my iMac 10.11.6, using the default email.
The last 2 months or so, I cannot send mail.  All my settings are correct.  I've had them checked by Apple, those who provide my mail service have logged into my computer to check the settings, and I've taken my computer in for support where I purchased it from a certified Apple Dealer.  I've run Malware as well. I receive email with no problem.  No one can seem to figure out why I cannot send.  The connection doctor indicates I cannot access the SMTP server.  Any ideas please.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/335622/edit) your question to specify certain crucial details like the email provider (iCloud, Gmail, Other etc.) that you wish to use. Mention the URL of the SMTP server that is unreachable. macOS doesn't generally have any setting which controls access to SMTP server(s). Possibly the server is not reachable over your network.

Comment: Hello Scott, welcome to Ask Different. The SMTP protocol is used to send email, can you receive email, that is, does IMAP/POP work? What is the output of Window>Connection Doctor in the Mail app (redact any personal information that could identify you like your email address when posting the output)? Could run `nc -v <SMTP server> <SMTP port>` in Terminal app and post the output?